# Linq to SQL with Repository Pattern and DDD

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to learn more about Domain Driven Development including the Repository pattern, Unit of Work, etc. and reading Fowler's book and Evans...but just started to do so. I want to setup an app to separate my Data Layer logic and structure from my BL (Domain).

If I use LINQ to SQL I assume this is simply creating my table-to-class tightly coupled objects which has nothing to do with DDD because I can then create a repo pattern and separate concerns between my DL (LINQ to SQL) and my BL logic...is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

LINQ to SQL is just going to map your relational DB to Objects - Entity Framework will do the same as will nHibernate and a plethora of others.  Once you have your domain objects mapped, which you are doing, then you can create your repositories and your units of work etc. right down the DDD line.

Check this action out for some heavy duty DDD goodness:

[microsoftnlayerapp](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks...ok but Domain objects are your BL classes rights?  Just another term for Business Layer Class/object...calling it Domain objects/classes.   So the mapping if you're going to go the LINQ to SQL route would have to be done by you...custom code right?

Comment: Yes - Domain Object == Business Object - they are the base "things" that you will build your domian around - things like employees and orders and customers etc...  If you go the Linq to SQL route your Domain/Business classes should be generated for you - I know in the Entity Framework they do a nice job of making POCO object that you can easily extend and IIRC Linq to SQL does the same thing.

Comment: wait so you have your DL classes (DTOs), your BL classes (workflow logic) and Presentation Layer.  What are you talking about then here when you say in general terms the domain?  Isn't that your BL?  And why would the Entity framework auto create your BL objects...they are very custom to your business domain and workflow logic you'll need in order to use that in your PL...so can you reiterate what you said...I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I've looked up POCO in wikipedia but have yet to know wtf it really means besides plain old class object or whatever.  Any links to example POCO articles or classes?  I have not found any that give me a real good feel for what they are in real world context and use.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict POCO means that Your class is not invaded with things like ISerializable interface, inheritance from UberHuge base class etc. So instead of thinking about how to implement every base class abstract method with `throw new NotImplementedException("haa haa")`, You are free to write code what actually matters. It's decoupled.

Comment: @Arnis, so are you essentially saying you're using these POCO classes via composition rather than inheritance?